# What is the conflict probability of md5 digestion if input string only contains alphanumericals

Tags: md5

The input strings have the following conditions:

- Only contain alphanumericals ([a-zA-Z0-9])
- The size of a string is always less than 256 bytes
- Total number of input strings is less then 1000,000

So what is the conflict probability of md5 digestion if the input strings are all under the above conditions? Can I just assume that there has no conflict?

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are random the [likelihood of a collision in that input set is very low](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/01/10/probability-of-secure-hash-collisions/#:%7E:text=As%20a%20rule%20of%20thumb,or%20about%204%20billion%20items.). That being said MD5 is a broken algorithm and a human can easily use software to find a collision. So you probably just shouldn't use MD5, but it depends on what you're using it for. I'm not sure why you would ever want to use MD5 anymore. You should look into the blake2 family or the newer SHAs (SHA256, SHA512, not SHA-1). If these are passwords you should pretty much definitely be using a hash designed for passwords like PBKDF2 or one of the Argons. To be honest I'd recommend just using libsodium's defaults for most things.